# Random Function Generator between two integers C++

Tags: c++, function, random

Assume you have a fully defined and correct function with the following prototype

```
int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound );
```

that returns a random number between the lower and upper bounds, inclusive.

Write a main function that uses randomBetween to generate 1000 values between 1 and 10, inclusive.
    As the values are generated, count how many times the value is equal to five.
    Display the number of times the value was equal to five.
    Your program should only output a single number (i.e., do not put the cout statement in a loop).

Here is what I have so far:

```
   // Function Prototypes
   int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound );

   int main( )
{

  int lowerbound, upperbound;

  cout << "Enter the value for the lower bound: " ;
  cin >> lowerbound;

  cout << "Enter the value for the upper bound ( lower < upper ) : " ;
  cin >> upperbound;

  cout << "The random value between " << lowerbound << " and "<< upperbound 
       << " is " << randomBetween << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound )
{
  int upperbound, lowerbound;
  int randomBetween = rand() % (upperbound-lowerbound) + upperbound;
  return randomBetween;
}
```

When I compile the program and enter in values for the lower and upper bounds, I get an answer of: 00E9131B

Comment: Mandatory: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly your C++ code contains a few errors. It looks like your returning the address of the function. Even if a function in C++ takes no parameters, when calling, you always must follow the function name with parenthesis: `function()`. In your case it does take parameters which need to be passed to it properly `function(param0, param1, param2)`. 
It looks like you are assuming because you named your variables `lowerbound` and `upperbound` the same as the function parameters that it will be implicitly passed, but that is not how C++ works. 
However you can define `lowerbound` and `upperbound` as global variables and not have your function `randomBetween()` take any parameters. You can set global variables by defining then **outside** the scope of a function.
You also need to initialize all variables. Just set `lowerbound` and `upperbound` to `0` when you define them.

Answer (score 3):

this:

```
cout << "The random value between " << lowerbound << " and "<< upperbound 
     << " is " << randomBetween << endl
```

Should be:

```
cout << "The random value between " << lowerbound << " and "<< upperbound 
     << " is " << randomBetween(lowerbound,uppderbound) << endl
```

In the randomBetween function, you do not need to declare the variables upperbound and lowerbound as they are already passed to the function.

Also it would be considered bad practice to name a variable the same name as a function, so you should probably rename the 'randomBetween' variable in the randomBetween Function.

You might want to take a look at the reference for the rand() function at, as your randomBetween function does not return a value in the desired range :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand

I'm not sure if you excluded it from what you have posted, but don't forgot to include the 'cstdlib' and 'iostream' libraries:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 3):

replace this line

```
cout << "The random value between " << lowerbound << " and "<< upperbound 
   << " is " << randomBetween << endl;
```

with this

```
cout << "The random value between " << lowerbound << " and "<< upperbound 
   << " is " << randomBetween(lowerbound, upperbound) << endl;
```

what you were doing is print out the function address. you need to call the function with arguments.

---

also change this

```
int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound )
{
  int upperbound, lowerbound;
  int randomBetween = rand() % (upperbound-lowerbound) + upperbound;
  return randomBetween;
}
```

to

```
int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound )
{
  int randomBetween = rand() % (upperbound-lowerbound) + upperbound;
  return randomBetween;
}
```

you don't need redeclare parameters again in function

Comment: when i do that, the compiler gives an error stating that the variables lowerbound and upperbound are uninitialized.

Comment: thanks xlc. what if i wanted to run the function 10 times using a for loop?

Comment: then just put the body of your main into a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not use the arguments,

```
int randomBetween( int lowerBound, int upperBound )
{
    int randomBetween = rand() % (upperBound-lowerBound) + upperBound;
    return randomBetween;
}
```

And call the function with arguments,

```
... << randomBetween(lowerbound, upperbound) <<endl;
```

Comment: when i do that, the compiler gives an error stating that the variables lowerbound and upperbound are uninitialized.